# How can I 'print' the number of objects returned from an API call into a view using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, javascript-objects

I am doing an `$http` request to an API and I am getting a total of 4 objects returned. I was wondering if there was a way I could get the number "4" that I consoled logged and put it on an html view with `ng-repeat`..

`console.log(data.length);`

[image]

I have done it with other keys and values of the JSON but I am not sure how to go about doing this with the total length of objects.

Why do I need this? Because each object represents the number of clients we have for that day and it would be very practical if I could print this number on to the screen every time the API is returned.. Any help would be awesome.. thank you all!

```
  self.getBookings = function () {
        //create 'defer object'
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("http://localhost/apiV2/bookings/1001")
        .success(function success (data) {
          console.log(data);
          console.log(data.length);

//this was my attempt to get the number "4"
          var passengerCount = data.forEach(function(passCount) {
            self.bookings.push({
              length: passCount.length
            });
          })


          self.bookings = data;

      };
```

Answer (score 1):

just assign the length to a scope variable and display in view

```
  $scope.totalCount =0;
  self.getBookings = function () {
        //create 'defer object'
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("http://localhost/apiV2/bookings/1001")
        .success(function success (data) {
          console.log(data);
          $scope.totalCount = data.length;
          self.bookings = data;

      };
```

And in view

```
<h1>{{totalCount}}</h1>
```

Here is a sample [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/cf945br1/).

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response! As soon as you said assign `$scope` I felt really silly because that's obvious and I didn't even remember. Thank you. However this solution is not working for me now.. I will continue to try.. I got `$scope is not defined` error..

Comment: You need to inject $scope to your controller

Answer (score 0):

use the concept of data bindings in Angular .js not very aware of the fact of angular.js but it seems this is classic example of data binding.

assign a length of data to a data binding variable . And use the state of that variable in your view part .

Comment: Indeed! I know I am close.. Thank you.. I will report when I am done.. I finally stop getting the error that scope is not defined but I still can't bind that number 4 to the view.. No errors to guide me either.. Thank you!